# Merging Sharepoint WSP files

Tags: office-365, solution-package, wspbuilder

I have a custom site template wsp file & workflow wsp file.

I am trying to combine these two wsp file to one.

Is that possible to do this in office 365 with sandbox solution, and if so, how?

Comment: Are `office-365` and `wspbuilder` tags 100% related?

Comment: yes office - 365 tag is 100% related, don't know about wspbuilder..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you'll have to replicate steps that Visual Studio automagically do for you ).

1. Extract `wsp`s. Because `.wsp` is `.cab` archive, you'll need a tool to deal with `cab`s. I used `Total Commander` plugin for the purpose. Extract into **separate** folders.
2. Merge content of `manifest.xml` from those folders into one `manifest.xml`
3. Merge files from those folders (copy/move)
4. Archive this merged folder into `.cab` file using tool
5. Rename `.cab` to `.wsp`

That is pretty easy unless you have files with the same name in both archives

Comment: If you need to do it regulary and you are developing those solutions,  there are another option using Visual Studio to create a single (Installer) SharePoint project

Comment: i'm confuse about  how to Merge content of manifest.xml,
because mainfest.xml contains <Solution SolutionId=""> 
and mainfest.xml contains only one Solution element

Comment: Each `wsp` corresponds to solution. You have to decide, either you want new solution that includes both `wsp`s or you want to upgrade one of the `wsp` with the other. I later case, you can keep the `SolutionId`

Comment: Here is the schema: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms412929.aspx

Comment: is there is any article for "Merging Sharepoint WSP files" step by step?